# Invalid_request_parameter (create and sending envelopes)

Tags: rest, docusignapi

I'm trying to use a service of DocuSign API in an abap project. I want to send a document to a specific email so it can be signed. But im getting the following error:

"errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER",##  "message": "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Query parameter 'from_date' must be set to a valid DateTime, or 'envelope_ids' or 'transaction_ids' must be specified.

I tried the following:

```
  CALL METHOD cl_http_client=>create_by_url
    EXPORTING
     url                = l_url (https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/XXXXXX')
     proxy_host         = co_proxy_host
     proxy_service      = co_proxy_service
    IMPORTING
     client             = lo_http_client

lo_http_client->request->set_method( method = 'POST').

    CALL METHOD lo_http_client->request->set_header_field
  EXPORTING
    name  = 'Accept'
    value = 'application/json'.


CALL METHOD lo_http_client->request->set_header_field
  EXPORTING
    name  = 'X-DocuSign-Authentication'
    value = get_auth_header( ). (json auth header)

CALL METHOD lo_http_client->request->set_cdata
  EXPORTING
    data = create_body( ).
```

This is my body:

```
  CONCATENATE
`{`
  `"emailSubject": "DocuSign REST API Quickstart Sample",`
  `"emailBlurb": "Shows how to create and send an envelope from a document.",`
  `"recipients": {`
   `"signers": [{`
     `"email": "test@email",`
     `"name": "test",`
     `"recipientId": "1",`
     `"routingOrder": "1"`
   `}]`
  `},`
  `"documents": [{`
   `"documentId": "1",`
   `"name": "test.pdf",`
   `"documentBase64":` `"` l_encoded_doc `"`
  `}],`
  `"status": "sent"`
`}` INTO re_data.
```

The api request to get the Baseurl is working fine. (I know the error is quite specific what the problem is, but i cant find any sources on the docusign api documentation that one of the mentioned parameters should be added to the request)

Thank you in regards

Comment: I'd say this is not related to the fact you're using ABAP to call the service, so I've removed the tag. Apart from that, I'd say the error message is rather clear...

Comment: We (DocuSIgn) would love to feature your integration of SAP and DocuSign. If this is of interest, please contact us via apihelp@docusign.com. Tell them Larry Kluger sent you. Please ask more questions if you run into any other issues.

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems to indicate that you're Posting to an endpoint that requires certain query string parameters -- but you're not specifying them as expected in the query string.  I'd suggest you check the DocuSign API documentation for the operation you are using, to determine what query string parameters it requires, and then ensure that you're including those parameters in your request URL.

If you can't figure this out using the documentation, then I'd suggest that you update your post to clarify exactly what URL (endpoint) you are using for the request, including any querystring parameters you're specifying in the URL. You can put fake values for things like Account ID, of course -- we just need to see the endpoint you are calling, and what qs params you're sending.

Answer (score 1):

To create an envelope, use

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/XXXXXX/envelopes
```

instead of

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/XXXXXX
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is the issue--wrong endpoint is being used. Thank you for answering the question!

Comment: While creating the post i copied the wrong url, but i was using the correct one (/envelopes), that was not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all the answers, i found the mistake. Creating the request wasn´t the problem. I was using the wrong "sending"-method -_-.

now its working :)

lo_rest_client->post( EXPORTING io_entity = lo_request_entity ).

Comment: Hi,do you mind sharing the entire code if possible